# How to implement Core Data migration for new Entity for existing app (if it's necessary)

Tags: core-data, nsuserdefaults, database-migration, data-migration

I just released an app called Twinstones three days ago and I've been updating it constantly, however I now wish to update my Core Data model object.  When users first open the app (and basically every time after), I use an `NSUserDefaults` object to check whether or not an initial setup of my model object has been conducted.  If the value of the default object is 0, it initializes the setup, if a 1, it ignores the setup.

At this point, obviously, the initial setups have been completed for all 70-some people who have downloaded the game.

I would like to add an Entity for a tutorial for the first level, and use Core Data to keep track of whether or not the tutorial has been viewed, which means I have to migrate the now-old model object to this new one with the new entity. Before I get into it, should I just use another `NSUserDefault` object (applied in the same manner as initial setup) to determine whether or not to run the tutorial on the first level?

If not, here is my code for the managed object context, managed object model, and persistent store coordinator:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// from website
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ScoreModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// from website
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]
                   URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Twinstones.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:storeURL
                                                     options:nil
                                                       error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

In my `persistantStoreCoordinator` method, how would I implement the migration?  Given the fact that the default object already went through initialization, I feel like I'd have to add another default object, get a reference to the current model object, migrate it and add the new Entity.

I've never actually done this before so really crack into the code (if, again, this migration is even necessary).  If I can just use another `NSUserDefaults` object with the near-guarantee that the property list in which it stores the data will never become malicious by accident, then I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

use the following dictionary:

```
 NSDictionary* configuration = @{
                        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES
                        };
```

For your configuration option when you add the store to the `persistentStoreCoordinator`.